# How to change a key value in a response using angular http

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, ionic-framework

I have a scenario where I'm getting the below `json` as response.

```json
[{
        "ImagePath": "/folder/images/products/1.jpg",
        "LanguageId": 2,
        "Id": 2,
    },
    {
        "ImagePath": "/folder/images/products/2.jpg",
        "LanguageId": 3,
        "Id": 3,
    }
]
```

Here I have domain name as `www.getimage.com` so now I'm combining `url = domainname + imagepath`.

```
e.g.  www.getimage.com/folder/images/products/2.jpg
```

But here the problem is whenever I hit the url it is redirecting to another url.

```
e.g.  www.getimage.com/protected/cart/img/products/2.jpg
```

How can I handle this image url redirection?

Comment: would you please share some logs or screenshots to make others understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give more info (how you invoke the get, ...), but, if I've understood well,
I supouse that you always receive an array of that kind, so maybe you can fix it with a `pipe` and some ImagePath `mapping` transformation, something like this:

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


return this.http
.get<SearchImageResponse[]>(this.url, { params})
.pipe<SearchImageResponse[]>( 
    map ( (_responseArray: SearchImageResponse[]) => (_responseArray.map( image =>  image.ImagePath = 'www.getimage.com' + image.ImagePath ) ) )
);
```

obviously, with your url, params, and  type...

or easier if you are doing 'your stuff' in a `subscribe`:

```js
this.http
.get<SearchImageResponse[]>(this.url, { params})
.pipe<SearchGifResponse[]>( 
    map ( (_responseArray: SearchImageResponse[]) => (_responseArray.map( image =>  image.ImagePath = 'www.getimage.com' + image.ImagePath ) ) )
)
.subscribe((response) => {
    // response should still be a SearchImageResponse[]
    response = response.map( (_responseArray: SearchImageResponse[]) => (_responseArray.map( image =>   image.ImagePath = 'www.getimage.com' + image.ImagePath ) ) );

}
```

or this one:

```js
let transformedArray:SearchImageResponse[] = [];

this.http
.get<SearchImageResponse[]>(this.url, { params})
.pipe<SearchGifResponse[]>( 
    map ( (_responseArray: SearchImageResponse[]) => (_responseArray.map( image =>  image.ImagePath = 'www.getimage.com' + image.ImagePath ) ) )
)
.subscribe((response) => {
    // response should still be a SearchImageResponse[]
        this._historialBusqueda.forEach( _img => {

      _img.ImagePath = 'www.getimage.com' + _img.ImagePath;

       transformedArray.push(_img);


    });
}
```

Sorry, I can't test this now, I'm not sure if this work. But I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Going off your title you want to map the key values in your response to a different value?

```
res.map( e => {
    e.ImagePath = e.ImagePath.replace('/folder/images/','/protected/cart/img/');
})
```

Although the rest of your post seems to suggest you have a problem with a redirect which seems to be a completely different question.